# Posting a new application on Play store as an update which uses same keytore file,package name etc

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore

I have hosted an Android application on play store.I have somehow managed to corrupt the source project and I am using Page on eclipse. My question is if  I create a new fresh project  using same package name, with same name of Application and use same Keystore file for signing the application and just version update. Can I add it to the Play store as an update to the existing hosted application?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can.**

Below is what [Google Developer help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) section says.

> - The Package Name of the updated APK need to be the same as the    current version.
> - The Version Code needs to be greater than that current version. Learn more about versioning your applications.
> - The updated APK needs to be signed with the same signature as the current version.

If you pass these requirement, it doesn't matter how many times you have created the same project. So don't worry!

Answer (score 0):

Yes , You can. If your using same application Id and signing key store and app version code +1